# How to convert every element of a string to int

Tags: c++11

I am trying to get the total sum of every digit of a big number which is stored in a string variable. So the first thing to do is to convert each element to an int and add it to the total sum. So my question is how can I convert an element of a string to an int? I tried using std::stoi but I got compiler error.

Here's my code anyway:

```
std::string x = "7825394359371498287";
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    sum += std::stoi(x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) wants a *string* and you give it a single character.

This problem can be easily solved by knowing the text encoding used as then you can easily convert a digit character to its corresponding number. Take for example the most common encoding system [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), which if you see the table in the provided link will tell you that the character `'7'` have the ASCII value `55`, while the character `'0'` have the value `48`. That should tell you that to get the number `7` from the character `'7'` all you have to do is subtract `'0'` from `'7'` (i.e. `55 - 48`), like so:

```
sum += x[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Oh, now I know. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can just subtract `0` from the char values.

```
std::string x = "7825394359371498287";
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    sum += x[i] - '0';
}
```

`stoi` gives an error because it works on strings and not single chars.

Comment: you were little faster

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
std::string::size_type sz;
std::string x = "7825394359371498287";
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.size();i++) {
    sum += std::stoi(x.substr(i,1), &sz);
}
```

other way:

```
std::string x = "7825394359371498287";
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
    sum += x[i] - '0';
}
```